# How to resolve findViewByID() returning Null after setContentView()

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a `Button` element in a Layout file, `add_site_bottom_sheet.xml` with the id `@+id/add_site_sheet_add_site_button`.

In my `SitesActivity.java`, in `onCreate()`, I call `buildAddSiteSheet()`.

In this method, I create an instance of a `BottomSheetDialog`, then I call `setContentView(R.layout.add_site_bottom_sheet)`.

After `setContentView(...)`, I assign `Button addSiteButton` with `findViewById(R.id.add_site_sheet_add_site_button)` but this is returning `null`.

I've looked in multiple places and cannot find any answers at the moment.

I was wondering if you lovely people would have a spy at my code to see if I'm missing anything.

**SitesActivity.java**

```
    public class SitesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        ITrapLossCalculator calc;
        ICustomer customer;
        Controller controller;

        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        SitesRecyclerViewAdapter recyclerAdapter;
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerManager;
        FloatingActionButton fab;
        BottomSheetDialog addSiteSheet;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.sites_screen);

            buildAppBar();           //method is omitted from this class

            Intent intent = getIntent();

            controller = intent.getParcelableExtra(CustomersActivity.EXTRA_CONTROLLER);
            calc = controller.getLossCalculator();
            customer = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_CUSTOMER);

            setTitle(customer.getName());

            buildRecyclerView();    //method is omitted from this class
            buildFAB();             //method is omitted from this class
            buildAddSiteSheet(); 

        }

        private void buildAddSiteSheet(){
            Button addSiteButton;
            addSiteSheet = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
            addSiteSheet.setContentView(R.layout.add_site_bottom_sheet);

            // addSiteButton below is null.
            addSiteButton = findViewById(R.id.add_site_sheet_add_site_button);

            addSiteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //TODO - Callback to add site to model needs to be implemented.
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

**add_site_bottom_sheet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <GridLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/BoilerAndValve"
        android:background="@color/colorBandVAccent"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="4">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/add_site_sheet_address_line_1_entry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:hint="@string/add_new_site_sheet_address_line_1_hint"
                android:autofillHints="no"
                tools:targetApi="o" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/add_site_sheet_address_line_2_entry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:hint="@string/add_new_site_sheet_address_line_2_hint"
                android:autofillHints="no"
                tools:targetApi="o"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/add_site_sheet_address_line_3_entry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:hint="@string/add_new_site_sheet_address_line_3_hint"
                android:autofillHints="no"
                tools:targetApi="o"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/add_site_sheet_postcode_entry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:hint="@string/add_new_site_sheet_postcode_hint"
                android:autofillHints="no"
                tools:targetApi="o"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/add_site_sheet_name_entry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:hint="@string/add_new_site_sheet_name_hint"
                android:autofillHints="no"
                tools:targetApi="o"/>


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/add_site_sheet_phone_entry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:hint="@string/add_new_site_sheet_phone_hint"
                android:autofillHints="no"
                tools:targetApi="o"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add_site_sheet_add_site_button"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:text="@string/add_site_button_text"/>


        </GridLayout>
```

I've ommited some methods in `SitesActivity.java` that I think are completely unrelated to keep things readable on SO, but if anyone thinks there might be anything there, I'll happily edit to include the other methods.

I would also like to add, I've tried getting all other elements from `add_site_bottom_sheet.xml`, but `findViewById(...)` returns null for those too.

I don't have any duplicate layouts and I don't have any other sizes of layouts yet either so I'm at a loss!

Comment: It should be `addSiteButton = addSiteSheet.findViewById(R.id.add_site_sheet_add_site_button);`

Comment: @ADM It's always something so simple... I've just not found myself in the situation where I've had to go about it this way. Thank you all for looking!

Comment: Thats because you don't know `#findViewById()` methods working . Read about before using any new thing.

Comment: @ADM That's a fair point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use

```
addSiteButton =(Button) addSiteSheet.findViewById(R.id.add_site_sheet_add_site_button);
```

Comment: it should be like this `addSiteButton =addSiteSheet.findViewById(R.id.add_site_sheet_add_site_button);`